# Display attributes @id, @name,@parent in single row

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have tags in XML where i have multiple attributes. @id, @name,@parent. When I open the XML in editor all three attributes are not getting displayed in single line.
Just like :

```
Test id="" name=""
 parent="" child=""
```

I wanted all these attribute in single line

```
Test id="" name="" parent="" child=""
```

I am transforming the XML using XSLT to get desired XML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the problem now with the XML editor you use or with a particular XSLT processor you use? You will need to explain exactly which software you use that gives the problem. If you use Saxon 9 for instance then there is an extension attribute `saxon:line-length` , see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.html, that gives you some control when attributes are put on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serializing the result tree of an XSLT transformation using the xsl:output controls on an XSLT processor, then the specification is prescriptive about some aspects of the serialization, but other aspects are left to the XSLT processor. There's nothing in the spec that constrains whether the attributes in a start tag are separated by spaces, tabs, or newlines, there's nothing that constraints whether single or double quotes are used around the attribute values, and there's nothing that constrains the order of attributes.

Your particular XSLT processor may have its own ways of allowing you to control such things. With Saxon, as @MartinHonnen mentions, attributes will only be wrapped onto a new line if the maximum line length would otherwise be exceeded, and you can set the maximum line length using a Saxon serialization option.

However, even if the XSLT serializer outputs it in a particular way, the XML editor is quite entitled to display it differently. The whitespace between attribute values is considered insignificant (in that it conveys no information to a receiving application), and XML tools in a processing pipeline are therefore not required or expected to retain it in its exact form.